# textAngular validation

Tags: angularjs, textangular

I am trying to validate textAngular fileds, I need to add required, max and min characters and border color on red/green on textAngular... I have for each loop and inide textAngulars...

Here is my code:

```
 <form ng-submit="addReply(x)" class="dd animated slideInDown" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <text-angular ng-minlength=10 ng-maxlength=600 required ta-text-editor-class="form-control myform1-height" ta-html-editor-class="form-control myform1-height" ta-toolbar="[['bold','italics']]" style="min-height: 100px; color:red;" ng-model="form.reply[x.pivot.comment_id]"></text-angular>

                <span  ng-show="form.reply[x.pivot.comment_id].$dirty && form.reply[x.pivot.comment_id].$invalid"></span>
                <span ng-show="form.reply[x.pivot.comment_id].$error.min || form.reply[x.pivot.comment_id].$error.max">
      The value must be in range 0 to 10!</span>
                <span ng-show="form.reply[x.pivot.comment_id].$error.required">Email is required.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <addreply></addreply>
            </div>
        </form>
```

My code don't work I don't know why...

Comment: What part exactly isn't working? Is any of the validation working? I think the ng-min/maxlength should have quotations around their values. ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="600" which could be causing the problem.

Comment: Not wotking: color on textarea, not show error messages...

Answer (score 0):

According to AngularJS documentation, your form and inputs should have names.
Then you should set validation `ng-show`'s to `form_name.input_name.$error` and so on, like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp)

Comment: But what if I have more more inputs with same name?

Comment: According to HTML standart you can't have more than one input with same name on the form.

Answer (score 0):

this one is a small example based on your question for

```
 validating the required field
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6PTNg3atPHAjL0XFtvWj?p=info